# Sql connection error or database table name error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, web-services

I have an error while debugging my program, it is a web service login and user tracking system with asp.net c#. Previously was the sql exception error, I've fixed it with changing the connection string and it changes to another error, below is my code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Login(string Username, string Password)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Username, Password from UserData where Username = @Username AND Password = @Password ", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    // Create an instance of DataSet.
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    string result = "Successful";

    int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    if (count == 1)
    {
        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
        con1.Open();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ActivityLog (CreateOn, CreateBy, UpdateOn, UpdateBy) VALUES (@CreateOn,@CreateBy, @UpdateOn, @UpdateBy ", con1);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateOn", dt);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateBy", Username);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdateOn", dt);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdateBy", Username);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        // Create an instance of DataSet.
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        da1.Fill(ds);
        con1.Close();
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        result = "Fail";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here's the error shown:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'UserData'.
```

I am not sure is it the connection string error or my code was incorrect?

Comment: It's telling you exactly what the problem is. It can't find an object in the database named UserData.  Double check that, that is in fact a valid table name and that the user performing the query has access to it.

Comment: I am unable to edit this question to improve the formatting, is there any problem with stackoverflow?

Comment: @JohnKoerner checked. My database has two tables which is UserData and ActivityLog.  Or it's because of my sqlconnection is wrong? I tried several version eg. copy from web.config, used configuration manager and all doesn't work, with an error Null exception. Finally i copied from my database properties and it works, the database i created on local in my visual studio 2010, is there any problem with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=192.168.68.42\SQL2017STD;Initial Catalog=YourDBNameHere;User ID=sampleusername;Password=yourpassword; connection timeout=6000" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: okay thanks a lot! but my database doesn't have username or password, what should i fill in?

Comment: Try to remove user and password.. or create username and password on your DB.

Comment: It keeps on loading, retry and still the same

Comment: Did you use the connectionstring? Try to use IP address

Comment: Yes i did, but the provider name cannot support so i removed it